# Delete article with submit button

Tags: php, html, css

i have a problem with deleting the articles. I want it to delete after click on submit button but i dont know how. I do not want use javascript to autosubmit form in select tag. Can u help me ? I would appriciate that.  Thanks.

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../includes/conn.php');
include_once('../includes/article.php');

$article= new Article;

if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
 if(isset($_POST['id'])){
  $id=$_POST['id'];

$query=$pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM articles WHERE article_id=?');
$query->bindValue(1, $id);
$query->execute();

header('Location: delete.php');

}

 $articles=$article->fetch_all();

?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CMS Tutorial</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>
    <br/>
    <h4>Delete article:</h4>
      <form action="delete.php" method="post" name="id">
      <select>
      <?php foreach($articles as $article){?>
          <option value="<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>"><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete article">
      </form>
  </div>
</body>
?>
```

Comment: Your `action` has to be the current page. Remove the value in `action`. Move `name="id"` to your `select` tag. Remove the `header()` redirect. This should at least get you pointed in the correct direction if not get it working.

Comment: Works, thank u so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` to the form instead of `delete.php` to execute the `php` code above  and i assume the file looks as your post .
and add `name="id"` to `select` element to grap the post value to manipulate instead of `form`.
i hope this works according to what you provide in your post.

```
session_start();

include_once('../includes/conn.php');
include_once('../includes/article.php');

$article= new Article;

if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
 if(isset($_POST['id'])){
  $id=$_POST['id'];

$query=$pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM articles WHERE article_id=?');
$query->bindValue(1, $id);
$query->execute();

header('Location: delete.php');

}

 $articles=$article->fetch_all();

?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CMS Tutorial</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>
    <br/>
    <h4>Delete article:</h4>
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
      <select name="id">
      <?php foreach($articles as $article){?>
          <option value="<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>"><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete article">
      </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, shift `name="id"` from **form** to **select**.

You are trying to get selected id of drop down, so the **name** should be given to **select**.

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post" name="id">
<select>
```

to

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<select name="id">
```

Another issue noticed in your code is, you should terminate execution
immediately after `header('Location: delete.php');` with `die();` or
`exit();` to ensure remaining lines should not be executed. In PHP,
`header()` is just a function which helps in setting header, and here
you are settling **Location** header, which further handled by browser
for taking necessary action (here redirection). So, `header()` does
not ensure stopping execution of remaining code.